# How to convert a list to NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I keep getting this list which is stored as NSString:

`(
    "one",
    two,
    "three",
    4
)`

How do I convert the values into NSArray?

Comment: where/how do you get them? it looks like the textual representation (description) of an NSArray ... ?!

Comment: It is actually from a JSON. `{"blocks": ["one", two, "three",4]}` and I stored it as a NSString. I did not use NSArray straight away as I am learning how to use Realm.

Comment: I dunno how you get your JSON value but `NSArray *array = [yourJSON objectForKey:@"blocks"]` should works cause "blocks" is a key who contains an array.

Comment: If it's from a JSON and your "blocks" is a dictionary, you can just write something along the lines of 

`NSArray *foo = [results objectForKey:@"blocks"];`  (if we consider results is your JSON object)

Comment: Or just `NSArray *foo = results[@"blocks"];`

Comment: This question is to short. To get dissent answer edit your question add there JSon text you are processing, show code which you use for parsing it and show what result do you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want help. You say in a follow-on comment that you get the string from JSON. What utility are you using? NSJSONSerialization, or a third party JSON library? Is the data being sent from a remote server as JSON, or are you converting a structure like an array or a dictionary to a JSON string? Post the code that creates the string you show, along with a clear picture of the flow  of data.

Comment: Please ask proper question so we an help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you provide more information about where this list comes from or how it's made, maybe i can be of more help.

Otherwise, you can convert your string in an array of strings by "splitting" when the `,` appears, like so :

Your initial string is saved as `myString`

You should first remove then `(` & `)` at the start and the end of your string, and then do this :

```
NSArray* foo = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

And `foo` now contains these values :

```
"one"
two
"three"
4
```

But I still think you should give a little more information as i said at the start of this answer, because I have a feeling this is not exactly what you're looking for.

EDIT : as I said in comments, because it's a JSON, simply get the results into a dictionary, and then do :

```
NSArray *array = [results objectForKey:@"blocks"];
```

Comment: Apparently, I cannot remove the first and last character of the string as it is behaving like NSCFArray not NSString as I will get unrecognised selector error. For example this is error that I get when trying to append the string: `-[__NSCFArray stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb89bf660c0`

Comment: Since you told me its a JSON object, can you try what me and @smiless wrote in the comments of your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in this form, convert your JSON response in a dictionary and simply get the value of keyword "blocks" in an array. For example if you have

```
NSDictionary *dict = {"blocks": ["one", two, "three",4]};
```

The following will be your array

```
NSArray *array = [dict valueForKey:@"blocks"];
```